# Cutting a Notch at the top a Rounded Cylinder

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, blender-osm

Fairly new with Blender. Please excuse the following question if it comes off to amateur! But certainly hope someone will be able to figure this out for me.

Essentially I want to cut a notch at the top of rounded cylinder. The cylinder is currently modelled with a Subdivision Modifier.

I tried using the Boolean Modifier using a rectangular box to cut the Difference from the cylinder. However, it leaves really bad stretch marks along the edges.

Any type of tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Andy

[image: Rounded Cylinder]

[image: Intersecting]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you choose to go the route of booleans, then here is the method I would use.

Quad cap the cylinder to begin with. Delete the Ngon faces top and bottom, and [grid fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html?#grid-fill) them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > <kbd>G</kbd> with the edges selected.

[image]

Next you can add modifiers. ***Order is important***, so here is the modifier stack:
[image]

[Bevel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html#bevel-modifier) and [Weighted Normal](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/weighted_normal.html#weighted-normal-modifier) are the key ones that help here, they will help eliminate alot of the shading issues that you will run into relying on boolean workflows.

Finally, enable [*Auto-Smooth*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/structure.html?#properties) in  *Properties ‣ Object Data ‣ Normals*

[image]

---

This is roughly the result you should end up with:

[image]

Comment: Wow, just what I was looking for! Thank you so much Timaroberts! You have yourself a good day!